# Compare two json dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to compare two dictionaries. One is a template, and one is stored in a specific file.

The code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

template = {"giorno": 21, "mese": "aprile", "ora": "21"}
newww = "palestra.json"


g_temp = template['giorno']

with open(newww, 'r') as f:
        n_temp = json.load(f)
        print n_temp
        n_temp_new = json.dumps(n_temp, ensure_ascii=False)
        print(n_temp_new)

if g_temp == n_temp_new['giorno']:
        print("no")
else:
        print("yes")
```

palestra.json :

```
{"giorno": 21, "mese": "aprile", "ora": "21"}
```

output:

```
{u'giorno': 21, u'mese': u'aprile', u'ora': u'21'}
{"giorno": 21, "mese": "aprile", "ora": "21"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prova.py", line 25, in <module>
    if g_temp == n_temp_new['giorno']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can I compare these two dictionaries?

Comment: `n_temp_new` is a string, not a dict, because `json.dumps` returns a string representation of a dict. You probably wanted to compare `g_temp` with `n_temp['giorno']`.

Comment: yes! now it works! sorry but i'm new with promgramming.
thanks ;)

Comment: In fact, you don't need the `n_temp_new = json.dumps(n_temp, ensure_ascii=False)` at all.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because `n_temp_new` is a string, not a dict and thus does not allow string indexing. Note that `json.dumps` returns a string representation of a dict but not a dict itself.

You probably wanted to compare `g_temp` with `n_temp['giorno']` like this:

```
if g_temp == n_temp['giorno']:
    print('no')
else:
    print('yes')
```